# Appending string to associative array

Tags: php, oop, associative-array

I am trying to append a property of my class to the end of a value stored in an associative array.

```
public $encoded_url = urlencode(get_permalink());

public $social_buttons = array(
    'facebook' => 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='.$this->encoded_url.'',
    'twitter' => '',
    'google-plus' => '',
    'linkedin' => '',
    'pinterest' => ''
);
```

However, I am faced with the following error:
`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE)`

Help would be appreciated, many thanks :)

Comment: How do you think - where `$this` comes from?

Comment: ["This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated."](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

Comment: @PeeHaa nobody reads manuals(

Comment: Sadly that's pretty much true

Comment: So basically have a `__construct` function that does `$this->social_buttons['facebook'] = 'https://blah.blah.blah?u='.$this->encoded_url;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$this does not exist in that context, you can only access $this from within a function.  I would suggest setting that value in the constructor.

Comment: Thank you for your straightforward and concise answer. :)